# get error Pulling from library/python no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries when Switch to windows containers

Tags: windows, jenkins-pipeline, containers

I try to use two dockerfile in my jenkins file .In the first stage i try to use a linux container to build project and in the second stage i try to switch to a windows container to launch unit tests using robotframework.

the code is:

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

RUN apk update \
  && apk add build-base python

RUN mkdir /.npm \
  && chmod 777 /.npm


ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/terraform"]
```

DockerFileForWindows

```
FROM python:windowsservercore-ltsc2022


# ROBOT + LIBRARIES
RUN pip install robotframework && pip install robotframework-selenium2library && pip install wheel && pip install robotframework-jsonlibrary
RUN pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary

CMD ["python"]
```

and my jenkins file:

```
  pipeline {

         agent none

        triggers {
            // poll repo every 2 minute for changes
             pollSCM('H/2 * * * *')
         }
        options {
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '2'))
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
        }

        parameters {
            booleanParam(name: 'E2E_TESTS', defaultValue: true, description: 'Lancer les tests unitaires')
            booleanParam(name: 'CI_DEPLOY', defaultValue: false, description: 'Deploy')
        }

       

        stages {

            stage('Install dependencies') {
                agent {
                 
                      dockerfile {
                          filename 'Dockerfile'
                       }
                     }
                steps {
                    sh 'npm install'
                }
            }
            stage('E2E Test'){
                when {
                    expression {
                        return params.E2E_TESTS
                       }
                    }

                    agent {
                                
                        dockerfile {
                            filename 'DockerFileForWindows'
                            }
                        }
                     steps {

                          bat 'pip list'
                          bat 'cd robotFramewokTests'
                          bat 'robot .'

                          

                            }
                       }
                }   
                
}
```

when i launch the pipeline i get the error:
**Step 1/2 : FROM python:windowsservercore-ltsc2022
windowsservercore-ltsc2022: Pulling from library/python
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries**

Answer (score 0):

you are pulling window based images, but your system supports linux/amd64. You have change your image of python/linux-amd64.